# Between equivalent in Stata

Tags: stata

I want to flag all rows that have salaries between 100,000 and 500,000. I have Data1.dta as:

```
ID  Salary
1   100000
2   65000
3   400000
4   5000000
```

Is there a way to create a flag variable in Stata using SQL's between operator or its equivalent?

The resulting dataset would look like this:

```
ID  Salary     six_figures
1   100000     1
2   65000      0
3   400000     1
4   5000000    0
```

I can only think of following

```
gen six_figures = 0
replace six_figures = 1 if salary == 100000
replace six_figures = 1 if salary == 100001
```

... and so on. Which would be inefficient and silly.

Comment: As previously edited, the spelling is Stata and has been so over almost all of the program's history. https://www.statalist.org/forums/help#spelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gen six_figures = 0
replace six_figures = 1 if inrange(salary,100000,500000)
```

or

```
gen six_figures = 0
replace six_figures = 1 if salary >= 100000 & salary <= 500000
```

Comment: There is no need for a two-step here. `gen six_figures = inrange(salary, 1e5, 5e5)`. Note that 999999 would be six figures too. More importantly, see https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/ or https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0099  oe https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0087